# ESP32C3 prints to serial after reset despite no "uart_write_bytes(...)" calls

Tags: uart, esp32, freertos, transmission

**Situation:**

An ESP32C3 running the Bluedroid BLE stack is connected via UART to another MCU which expects to *always* receive constant length messages. The system seems to work perfectly fine during normal operation, but if I for whatever reason reset the ESP32, the ESP32 writes exactly one byte to UART, hence throwing off the receiver MCU by one byte!

**What I tried so far:**

I commented out *any* call to `uart_write_bytes()`, which in turn ensures that my program is not at fault. This change doesn't help though, as the ESP32 still keeps printing the byte upon reset.

**What the ESP send onto UART:**

- Upon hitting the "RST" button on the dev. board or flashing new software, it prints `0xfc`.
- If I unplug and replug the power however, it prints `0xf8`.

**N.B.:** I tried to reproduce such behavior on another microcontroller, specifically an STM32L552ZE. I was not able to, i.e. the STM32 didn't print anything to UART after resetting.

**Configuration (sdkconfig.json):**
As the file was too long to paste it directly, you can find it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ee49rSh7)

**Questions:**

1. Is there some configuration option that causes the ESP32 to print that initial byte?
2. How can I fix that behavior, i.e. make the ESP32 not print anything after resetting/flashing/startup

Comment: I think you can’t avoid the initial junk byte after MCU reset/power-cycle. On reset or power cycle the UART Tx pin is configured (from default input with pull-up to UART Tx function) and the receiver might detect UART protocol START bits and receives a phantom byte. Your protocol has to deal with that and resync to a valid message frame.

Comment: Use UART1 and leave UART0 for debugging purposes (bootloader and console interface).

Comment: HS2 thanks, that's exactly what I dreaded :')
rustyx I am already on UART1.

Comment: UART is not by any means a reliable channel. There are occasionally bytes added (as you've seen), lost, garbled - like with any physical channel. You must take this into account. A protocol must exist which defines the start and end of your frame, a checksum, maybe a sequence number - the usual stuff. E.g. as a bare minimum I've used SLIP as the framing protocol, plus a very simple XOR-over-payload-bytes as the checksum.